# Allow access to AWS S3 bucket via VPC within AWS without authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-eks, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-vpc

Is there any way to allow access to objects in an AWS S3 bucket via VPC within AWS without authentication? I don't want to use AWS IAM role or user for this. I don't want to disable access for all except VPC as objects are supposed to be accessed via AWS IAM role outside AWS.

Purpose: To provide AWS S3 bucket access to GitLab Runners running inside AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster on private nodes.

*Note: Public access is blocked and will remain blocked. All of the objects are private and will remain private.*

Comment: Are you doing this because your client application running in VPC can only access S3 objects via HTTP URL and not via AWS SDK? Have you also considered options like [Mountpoint for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/mountpoint-amazon-s3/)?

Comment: @jarmod I did this to provide access to GitLab runners running in AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster on private nodes. Of course, there are many solutions but I wanted to implement something that doesn't require any changes on the GitLab runner or Kubernetes side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can allow access to objects in an AWS S3 bucket via VPC within AWS without authentication using an AWS VPC endpoint (VPCE) for S3 and a bucket policy on that AWS S3 bucket.

Points to consider:

- AWS VPC endpoint (VPCE) should be created for `S3` service with `Gateway` type in the same region in which the AWS S3 bucket exists with the desired AWS VPC and route tables selected along with `Full Access` policy.
- AWS S3 bucket policy should only allow that AWS VPC endpoint.

A sample AWS S3 bucket policy will be as follows:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-access-to-S3-bucket-via-VPC-endpoint",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET_NAME]/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "[VPCE_ID]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `[BUCKET_NAME]` and `[VPCE_ID]` will be replaced with the appropriate values accordingly.

Source: [How can I configure my Amazon VPC to privately connect to my S3 bucket without using authentication?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication)